# Updated rows based on specific string placed in specific place

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to make sql query that would change specific text placed between second occurence of / and third occurence of / to specific text for all rows which contains specific word. So let's take example below i bolded string which are placed like mentioned above:

> /DUREN - RS7/**TAMBURLAGER**/RS7-TAMB-COVER-2/IMG_9140.JPG
>
> /OHTER IO/**MAN-SIX as 56**/MACHINE4/pic 56.jpg
>
> /DUREN - RS7/**Optislit Goebel**/RS7-BARRIER-6/IMG_9141.JPG
>
> /DUREN - RS7/**Optislit Goebel**/R-BARRIER-6/IMG_33.JPG
>
> /DUREN - RS7/**Optislit Goebel**/RS7-BARRIER-7/IMG_9143.JPG
>
> /Cars/**MaszynaAniaZawiera2**/Elementzawiera1/IMG_0152 - Copy.JPG
>
> /Aanekoski Supercalander 2014/**SC4 Unwinder Operator
> side**/SC4-LF2/IMG_2486.JPG
>
> /DUREN - RS7/**Optislit Goebel**/RS7-BARRIER-6/IMG_9142.JPG
>
> /DUREN - RS7/**Optislit Goebel**/RS7-BARRIER-9/IMG_9148.JPG
>
> /OHTER IO/**MAN-SIX as 56**/MACHINE4/pic-11.jpg
>
> /OHTER IO/**MAN-SIX as 56**/MACHINE1/pic3.jpg
>
> /Aanekoski Supercalander 2014/**Supercalander 4 Drive
> side**/SC4-D-CL1/IMG_3769.JPG
>
> /Aanekoski Supercalander 2014/**Electriccabinets**/EC1-1/IMG_2745.JPG
>
> /Aanekoski Supercalander 2014/**SC5Unwinder
> Drive**/SC5-D-F1-SW1/IMG_5304.JPG
>
> /Cars/MaszynaAniaZawiera2/**Elementzawiera1**/IMG_0148 - Copy.JPG

and now - let's take i want only to found those which string is
**MAN-SIX as 56** and then change it to **WHATEVER-11**

so based on mentioned example we got 3 rows which contain it:

> /OHTER IO/**MAN-SIX as 56**/MACHINE4/pic 56.jpg
>
> /OHTER IO/**MAN-SIX as 56**/MACHINE4/pic-11.jpg
>
> /OHTER IO/**MAN-SIX as 56**/MACHINE1/pic3.jpg

so finally based on example those rows should be changed to:

> /OHTER IO/**WHATEVER-11**/MACHINE4/pic 56.jpg
>
> /OHTER IO/**WHATEVER-11**/MACHINE4/pic-11.jpg
>
> /OHTER IO/**WHATEVER-11**/MACHINE1/pic 3.jpg

How to achieve that in secure way as i got millions of records and this have to be secure enough to not touch anything else than should be?

Thanks in advance.

**For further discussion:**

```
 select 
    stuff([PicturePath], charindex('/', [PicturePath], charindex('/', [PicturePath]) + 1) + 1, 13, 'WHATEVER-11') as new_data
from [WojtGroup].[dbo].[tbElemPics]
where substring([PicturePath], charindex('/', [PicturePath], charindex('/', [PicturePath]) + 1) + 1, 14) = 'MAN-SIX as 56/'
```

Comment: Question, is the text ```MAN-SIX as 56``` always between the 2nd / and the 3rd /?

Comment: as mentioned - yes we looking for specific text to be replaced always between 2nd occurence of / and 3rd occurence of /

Comment: Try to use: replace(col, 'MAN-SIX as 56', 'WHATEVER-11')

Comment: We need to know which SQL dialect.  Some have regexp_replace, which could do the job.

Comment: @PaulKienitz the question is tagged by SQL Server ;).

Comment: @ShenglinChen it can be more specific by using this : `replace(col, '/OHTER IO/MAN-SIX as 56/', '/OHTER IO/WHATEVER-11/')` ;).

Comment: No regexp_ replace in sql server, unless you extend it with .net, per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @string      VARCHAR(100)=N'/OHTER IO/MAN-SIX as 56/MACHINE4/pic 56',
        @replacewith VARCHAR(100)=N'WHATEVER-11'

SELECT Substring(@string, Charindex('/', @string, Charindex('/', @string)+1)
                          + 1, Charindex('/', @string, Charindex('/', @string, Charindex('/', @string)+1)
                                                       + 1) - Charindex('/', @string, Charindex('/', @string) + 1) - 1) AS substring
SELECT @string                                                                                                                    AS ActualData,
       Stuff(@string, Charindex('/', @string, Charindex('/', @string)+1)
                      + 1, Charindex('/', @string, Charindex('/', @string, Charindex('/', @string)+1)
                                                   + 1) - Charindex('/', @string, Charindex('/', @string) + 1) - 1, @replacewith) AS ReplacedData
```

Prepare try with this select for testing your scenario.

```
select Stuff(PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)
                                      + 1, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)
                                                                      + 1) - Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath) + 1) - 1, 'WHATEVER-11')
                                                                      from tbElemPics
WHERE  Substring(PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)
                             + 1, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)
                                                             + 1) - Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath) + 1) - 1) = 'MAN-SIX as 56'
```

Use this Update Statement

```
UPDATE tbElemPics
SET    PicturePath = Stuff(PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)
                                      + 1, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)
                                                                      + 1) - Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath) + 1) - 1, 'WHATEVER-11')
WHERE  Substring(PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)
                             + 1, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)
                                                             + 1) - Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath) + 1) - 1) = 'MAN-SIX as 56'
```

Comment: This is pure dynamic statement. Please change this as select statement check your results. Once you are fine with it then run the update.

Comment: can you change your select that i could use it again my table which is called: [tbElemPics] and column name is PicturePath

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, i am testing your select based also on diffrent strings and i realased that e.g for this string it will not work:  /Signal Paperu T.Iskanowskis Włocławek/Antegrexu - Mocioł/Pos81/IMG_8101.JPG

Comment: Any feedback on above comment?

Comment: i suppose it will not work when string would contain chars like: ę ą ś ż etc... Is that correct? Is there any way to tune your queries for that or it will only work when within string would be letters, digits, - and spaces ?

Comment: Would like to be sure of those two things.

Comment: If that possible please reply me

Comment: Two things i want to know are: 1) Instead of using char like ą ę ś ż does would it work at all?

Comment: If you can please give me some feedback

Comment: StackUser: (ą ę ś ż) These are multi-byte characters so you should use like @string VARCHAR(100)=N'/Signal Paperu T.Iskanowskis Włocławek/Antegrexu - Mocioł/Pos81/IMG_8101',

Comment: Hi NewUser ! Thanks for response. Note that PicturePath column is nvchar(300) type. According to your last comment is it possible to tuning your query to be also prepared for such situation ?

Comment: should i simply change your query at the end e.g from 'MAN-SIX as 56' to N'MAN-SIX as 56' ??

Comment: Yes try with that or else try to use "COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin"

Comment: ok i will try with N' on the beggining and come here later, can you tell me ecatly what diffrence it makes when i will be adding this N' ?

Comment: ok seems when i am using: N' before looking string e.g:  'MAN-SIX as 56' to N'MAN-SIX as 56'  it is working. Are you completly sure that now there is no way/situation this query could fail or? I am gonna to deploy on production... And second question is that mean that this N' just give possibility to also look on characters like ą ę ś ż etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92256/discussion-between-newuser-and-stackuser).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)  and [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) ;

Select statement [`sqlfiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24c1a/3):

```
select 
    stuff(data, charindex('/', data, charindex('/', data) + 1) + 1, 13, 'WHATEVER-11') as new_data
from tbl
where substring(data, charindex('/', data, charindex('/', data) + 1) + 1, 14) = 'MAN-SIX as 56/'
```

update statement [`sqlfiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e631f/1):

```
update tbl
set data = stuff(data, charindex('/', data, charindex('/', data) + 1) + 1, 13, 'WHATEVER-11')
where substring(data, charindex('/', data, charindex('/', data) + 1) + 1, 14) = 'MAN-SIX as 56/'
```